# TweenJS using requestAnimationFrame pauses on tab switch

Tags: canvas, createjs, tween, requestanimationframe, tween.js

I use `createjs.TweenJS` for twining objects on my canvas game. Problem is when I switch tab, Tween pauses and continues process after tabs is focused back.

My goal is to show stage state on current time situation, when tab is focused back. If say it in different way, when I switch tab, processes mustn't pause, but run in background.

If I switch TweenJS timing mode to TIMEOUT instead of requestAnimationFrame (RAF), everything works well.

Is it possible to achieve same result using requestAnimationFrame timing mode?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the features of RAF. It has a non-deterministic frequency, and allows the browser to throttle or even completely pause background animations to prevent hidden content from burning CPU and battery. It's managed by the browser, and you have no control over it.

If I recall correctly, some browsers (ex. Safari) will also throttle timeout events to some extent.

Take a look at the page visibility API, available in all modern browsers, and you should be able to track the elapsed time between when the tab was hidden to when it was shown, and react accordingly.